# Why is my jogl frame eating so much resources?

Tags: java, performance, opengl, jogl

I started making a game and I was experimenting with the graphics. After some time I wanted to check the task-manager to see how efficient the program is using the GPU instead of the CPU. And what I saw was that my GPU was 98% busy because that program was running. I was drawing around 100 textures on the screen.. I reduced it to nine and still.. 30% busy. I commented everything out to find the problem but without success. In the end I only had the bare frame that looked like this

```
    GLProfile.initSingleton();
    profile = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2);
    GLCapabilities caps = new GLCapabilities(profile);

    window = GLWindow.create(caps);
    window.setSize(screenWidth, screenHeight);
    window.setRealized(true);
    //window.addGLEventListener(new EventListener());
    //window.addMouseListener(new MouseInput());

    FPSAnimator animator = new FPSAnimator(window, 60);
    animator.start();

    window.setVisible(true);
```

I also tried the code from an other person on this website: http://schabby.de/jogl-example-hello-world/

I added an `FPSAnimator` to the panel on 60 FPS and my GPU was also suffering with this code.
When I draw 100 images with plain java my CPU can handle this better than the GPU and openGL. And that sounds absolutely wrong. What am I doing wrong? I ran out of ideas.

My graphics-card is a Geforce gtx 660 ti.

**Edit**

I noticed that when I start the program everything is good. But over time my GPU gets more and more busy and after like 10 seconds ist at 30-40%. It sounds like some kind of memory leak but I don't know if something like this applies to GPUs.

Comment: At first, the title of your question is plain wrong, misleading and disparages JOGL, please modify it as soon as possible. Secondly, the tutorial you use is a very bad one, its author published an even crappier video tutorial on Youtube and refused to edit it for years despite my warnings, it's uselessly complicated in many aspects and plain wrong in some aspects. Please use the latest release candidate of JOGL 2.4, put jogamp-fat.jar into the libraries of your project (you don't need to use several JARs except when you know what you do and you want to reduce the size of the dependencies).

Comment: Do you have the same problem with this official example I wrote? https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Rudimentary_standalone_example_using_the_fixed_pipeline_by_Julien_Gouesse The fat JAR is here: https://jogamp.org/deployment/v2.4.0-rc-20200307/fat/jogamp-fat.jar

Comment: Yes, my problem also applies to this code with the jogamp-fat library. It runs smoothly but the gpu load is at 15-20%. (looks cool tho)

Answer (score 1):

So it turned out that windows was the issue. Everytime I restart the task-manager the gpu load goes back to around 6% which is totally fine. So there is accually something wrong in the windows 10 task-manager. This is also extremly weird but I think there is the problem. Thaks for your time! (and now I can begin my project without any worries :) )

Comment: Can you just tell us whether you use a virus scanner?

Comment: Please call GLBase.setSwapInterval(1), maybe the vertical synchronization is disabled by default, maybe vertical synchronization is broken in your driver, disabling it mignt be problematic in some cases: https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/geforce-graphics-cards/5/153769/gtx-660-with-vsync-off-no-signal-crash/ JOGL isn't to blame.

Comment: Yes I have Kaspersky installed and it says that everything is ok (after full scan). I now tested it with an app (logitech) that shows me the gpu load. And There its constantly on 5%. But when I start the taks-manager the load rises slowly on both displays. I also tried it on an other pc and there the same thing occured.

Comment: It seems not to be related to JOGL. Thank you for the feedback.